# iOS: Is there a way to replace the default accessibility / voice over double tap action on an element with a custom one?

Tags: ios, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I know that it is possible to add custom accessibility actions by adding them to the accessibilityCustomActions array of the corresponding view.

But that does not replace the standard action that is performed when you do a voice over tap (you will have to swipe first to select the custom action).
I would like to replace the default tap action or intercept the tap event ... is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Absolutely! Override [`bool accessibilityActivate()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1615165-accessibilityactivate) to implement a custom default action.

Comment: make sure cell is accessible: `cell.isAccessibilityElement = true`