# Voice over in UICollectionView - some translations are missing

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, accessibility, voiceover

I'm trying to implement voice over in my app and I'm using Xamarin.Forms.
I've implemented custom grid control and on the iOS side I'm using renderer which internally uses UICollectionView.

In general all standard elements of my app - for instance traits of buttons, tap bar buttons etc. are translated well to my selected language, but in case of UICollectionView, two translations are missing:

- when I swipe down my list using tree fingers I always hear english translation "page x of y"
- when I do pull to refresh I always hear english translation "refreshing content"

I've tried to manipulate AccessibilityLanguage property, but this doesn't help also.

Any ideas?

I'm testing app on iPhone 11 with iOS 14.1.
I've checked other apps on the phone e.g. Apple Health, Twitter, Spotify and it looks like this is working well in this apps.

Comment: You could share the relevant code ,which will be helpful to check and reproduce the issue .

Comment: Right know it's a little bit complicated because there is a lot of code for this thing. I'll try later to divide this into small, standalone project.

Comment: If so I think the missing is caused by system design. You could set custom voice over when scrolling the CollectionView . Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913041/ios-is-there-a-way-to-replace-the-default-accessibility-voice-over-double-tap and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57552123/ios-voiceover-for-custom-view-displayed-over-uiviewcontroller

Comment: I set UIAccessibilityElement on every cell earlier and it's working well. But somehow those system messages for UICollectionView in this particular scenario are not translated.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution.

I didn't have set this key in `info.plist`:

```
CFBundleLocalizations
```